# In MVC 4 my textarea is not resetting from default value

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I've created a MVC project with Browse button and upload button. When the user clicks on Browse and select a file and click upload, the file contents has to be displayed in a Textarea. By default when I load the page, I'm displaying default text in textarea. Once the user uploads a file, I'm trying to display the contents in that textarea.

Problem is while I'm trying to reset the content, the textarea is not getting reset. Any help is really appreciated.

View:-

```
@model DigitalUnderwritingFacade.Models.DigitalUnderwritingModel
<h2>DigitalUnderwriting</h2>

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {       
        <table style="vertical-align:middle">
            <tr>                            
                <td>Upload a json file : <input type="file" id="btnbrowse" name="browse" value="Browse"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnfileUpload" name="btnfileUpload" value="Upload" /></td>
                <td><div id="validateSelectedFile" class="warrningMessage">Please browse a valid json file</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>                
                <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.JsonText, new { @class = "form-control", cols = "120", rows = "45", @id = "textarea" })</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="Savebtn" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }   
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $("#btnfileUpload").click(function () {       
        var formData = new FormData();
        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("btnbrowse").files.length;
        var browsedFile = document.getElementById("btnbrowse").files[0];
        var fileextension = browsedFile.name.split('.').pop();

        if (totalFiles == 0)
            $("#validateSelectedFile").show()
        if ((totalFiles != 0)) {             
            if (fileextension == 'json') {                
                formData.append("FileUpload", browsedFile);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/DigitalUnderwriting/Upload',
                    data: formData, 
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (result) { }                    
                });
            }
            else {
                alert("Please select a valid json file.");
            }
        }
    });   
</script>


Controller:-

 DigitalUnderwritingModel model = new DigitalUnderwritingModel();
        private string InputJsonPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultJson"].ToString();
        private string ResponseJsonPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JsonResponsesPath"].ToString();
        //
        // GET: /DigitalUnderwriting/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(InputJsonPath);
            if (TempData["ResponseJson"] == null)
            {
                model.JsonText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            else
            {
                model.JsonText = TempData["ResponseJson"].ToString();
                TempData["ResponseJson"] = null;
            }
            return View(model);
        }     


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            ModelState.Remove("JsonText");
            var streamfile = new StreamReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream);
            var streamline = string.Empty;
            while((streamline = streamfile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                model.JsonText += streamline;
            }
            TempData["ResponseJson"] = model.JsonText;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

Model:-

 [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
 public string JsonText { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, my friend. I think you dont need set id for Textarea.

```
$("#btnfileUpload").click(function () {       
    var formData = new FormData();
    var totalFiles = document.getElementById("btnbrowse").files.length;
    var browsedFile = document.getElementById("btnbrowse").files[0];
    var fileextension = browsedFile.name.split('.').pop();

    if (totalFiles == 0)
        $("#validateSelectedFile").show()
    else{            
        $('#JsonText').html(browsedFile.name); //set name file            
        if (fileextension == 'json') {                
            formData.append("FileUpload", browsedFile);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/DigitalUnderwriting/Upload',
                data: formData, 
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) { }                    
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Please select a valid json file.");
        }
    }
}); 

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            TempData["ResponseJson"] = model.JsonText;
            ModelState.Remove("JsonText");
            var streamfile = new StreamReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream);
            var streamline = string.Empty;
            while((streamline = streamfile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                model.JsonText += streamline;
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I need textarea ID to get the current value in the textarea. 

Here, I'm trying to show a default json in the textarea and when the user uploads a file, I'm trying to overwrite that file content with default..

Comment: @user1155576: Oh, you can get value of textarea very simple. $('#JsonText').val(). No need set new id for it :))

Comment: Whenever I'm loading the page, I'm showing the default text in textarea. In Upload button click how can I clear the textarea content and update it with file content ?

Comment: In my Controller HTTPPOST ActionResult method, I'm getting the file content and Redirecting to Index method to assign value to my Model Property (JsonText). This value I'm using in my View. Still it is displaying old value..

Comment: @user1155576: After call ajax or when, my friend?